# How to draw a shape dynamically on map touched location in android

Tags: google-maps, drawing, android-maps-v2

I want to draw a shape, wherever the user touches the map, the should be drawn dynamically. I don't have any idea about drawing these shapes. How could I achieve this? Can I get this done through canvas? I am using MapFragment.

Please see the image,

[image]

Please give me any idea!! Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Nobody know about this? Any one please!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by adding a `View` overlaying the map.

- have a `Polyline` object (initially empty) that will be your line
- handle onTouchEvent on that `View`
- translate x,y from events to `LatLng` using `Projection`
- add new point to `Polyline`

And you are done.

Note that this consumes all the events that would otherwise make map pan or zoom. You will have to have some other way to interact with map or enable consuming events using some flag.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with this. Hope this will help.

Comment: @Mahe are solved it? if yes could you share your code please? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: @Eman87, I have answered for your question and posted my code. Hope that will be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a ImageView overlying on the map. You can't draw on map.
2. The ImageView should implement "OnTouchListener"
3. Add any button on map, so as to bring the ImageView to front and map will be visible on background.
   4.when touched on ImageView, perform the below action

   ```
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int action = event.getAction();
   Point p = new Point();
   path = new Path();
   float upX;
   float upY;

   switch (action) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       laArray = "";
       lnArray = "";
       canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
       downx = event.getX();
       downy = event.getY();
       eventX = downx;
       eventY = downy;
       Log.d("", "startx" + eventX);
       p.x = (int) downx;
       p.y = (int) downy;
       LatLng latlngpoint;
       latlngpoint = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(p);
       break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
       upx = event.getX();
       upy = event.getY();
       canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
       drawable.invalidate();
       downx = upx;
       downy = upy;
       Log.d("", "Action_Move");
       Log.d("", "downx, downy: " + downx + "," + downy);
       Log.d("", "upx, upy: " + upx + "," + upy);
       p.x = (int) upx;
       p.y = (int) upy;
       LatLng latlngpoint1;
       latlngpoint1 = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(p);           
       break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       upX = event.getX();
       upY = event.getY();
       p.x = (int) upX;
       p.y = (int) upY;
       Log.d("", "Action Up");
       canvas.drawLine(eventX, eventY, upX, upY, paint);
       LatLng latlngpoint2;
       latlngpoint2 = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(p);           
       drawable.invalidate();

       // When finger is Up, Start UserSearch.

       StartUserSearch(); //user defined function
       return true;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
       break;
   default:
       break;
   }

   return true;
   ```

   }

Add ImageView like this,

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewOnMap"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

  </ImageView>
```

so, when the draw button on map is clicked,

```
 ImageView drawable= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewOnMap);
 drawable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 drawable.bringToFront();
```

Now, you should be able to draw on the imageView, but it seems that you are drawing on the map.

You can modify the code according to your requirement. Hope this will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks too much for your answer. I have a question. When you back to map and drag it to show any other location, is the line drawn move with map or it still steady in its place and the map moves under it?

Comment: @Eman87,When I come back to map, I am clearing the line drawn. When the user changes his location for searching, and if the user wants to search in that location, user will again click on the draw button on the map, and user is allowed to draw on imageView.

Comment: what is the use of  laArray variable I m getting error in that.

Comment: @jyomin I am using this variable to hold all the latitude and longitude values which fall in the shape drawn. My search is based on that array. I need the array of longitudes and latitudes.

Comment: I have implemented your onTouch method but nothing is drawn on the imageview..Please help

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can't.

As you can see the gesture will be consumed by the map for **pan/scroll** action.

But there is a **trick**.

- You can place a marker on user action (Long press on map)
- Set marker draggable and set the drag listener
- Prompt user to drag the marker
- Drag listener will consume the dragged points as user drags the marker.
- on Drag ends create a path with the Lat-Long and draw the path
- Remove the marker.