# use extends com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView un google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to use ( extends com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView ) to show maps in google map v2, meaning that I want to use both mapView to use its methods like onTouchEvent to draw free lines by fingers using canvas on the map and I want to use the markers in the google map v2.
Is it possible to combine both features?
Hope anyone got my mean. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work.

You may just combine your `CustomView` with `MapView` like this:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <MapView ... />
    <CustomView ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Not MapView in layout, in layout it is fragment tag I want to use (extends MapView) in the class to be able to use postInvalidate() method in google map v2 and draw lines

Comment: @Eman87 The same will work if you replace MapView with fragment. You can handle events and do the drawing in your `CustomView`.

Comment: I done this really but the problem is that when I drag map, it doesn't drag the lines in the customView with the map and I want the line move with the map.. and this is my problem. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968390/draw-over-google-map-v2-android .. I don't know how to use onTouchEvent in this app

Comment: @Eman87 Then you are doing it the wrong way. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976761/how-to-draw-a-shape-dynamically-on-map-touched-location-in-android/16983181#16983181