# How do I allow user to select area on Google Map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to allow user to select a region on Map( Could be state,city, or combinations of city or any small region like apartment community). User can draw a circle by hand gesture or by some other interactive way to select the region.

Based on that region, I want to do some computing. (So i would probably need coordinates and radius of selection or area of selection)

Is it possible to use Google maps for this purpose? If yes, how. Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.

The easist would be to handle `onMapClick`s: on the first click you store central `LatLng`, on the second, you calculate radius using [`Location.distanceBetween`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29) and create `Circle` out of it.

The above seems like a bad UX, so you could also try having an overlay `View` that consumes `DOWN` and `MOVE` `MotionEvent`s. On `DOWN` you create `Circle` object, on `MOVE` you update its radius.

Conceptually this answer could also help you with the second approach: [How to draw a shape dynamically on map touched location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976761/how-to-draw-a-shape-dynamically-on-map-touched-location-in-android/16983181#16983181).